# How to hide Docker containers behind a single hostname

Tags: networking, dns, docker, hostname, fqdn

I'm pretty new to Docker. I started by approaching with the VM mindset, but I'm realizing that it uses a whole different paradigm from VMs, or even traditional LXC containers.

The biggest challenge has been with understanding how networking works. I'm trying to use Docker to run multiple services on a machine that require some of the same ports, to avoid port conflicts.

I want to access all of them using the FQDN of the host machine, without having to worry about adding the container FQDNs to DNS. I'm forwarding the relevant container ports to unused host ports.

The problem is that, when I try to access the services from my browser, it's redirected to the FQDN of the container, which it can't resolve. The result is a "Server not found" error.

Is there a way to hide all the containers behind the host's FQDN, without ever having to resolve the containers' FQDNs?

Comment: have you considered [proxying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828699/multiple-docker-containers-as-web-server-on-a-single-ip/27828950#27828950)?

Comment: I tried using an Apache reverse proxy running on the host (CentOS 7). Perhaps I configured it wrong, but it didn't work. It still redirects to the containers hostname. My understanding is that "ProxyPassReverse http://<container-fqdn>:<port>" should prevent redirects being shown in the browser, but I'm seeing the container's address there. Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to give the container a static address, which makes it hard to configure a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You can make each docker container use a different outside port and then have a server docker with something like nginx or apache that reverse proxies the requests. I had to build something like this that takes everything in at one hostname and then passes through all the traffic to the appropriate container and port.

The difficulty is docker containers having new addresses each time they're created. You can dynamically figure out their addresses when they start up and have the proxy container start last with those addresses. The way you can grab those addresses is with a 'docker inspect' and awk the data you want, or you can use one of these libraries like docker-py to grab the relevant data.

Comment: It seems like there should be a more elegant way to manage this, besides having to figure out the IP every time. I thought of binding the loopback IP to the exposed ports on the container. Then Apache or Nginx could forward requests to this address. There must be a way that this is "meant" to be done.

Comment: It seems that the answer is [here](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/). I was hoping for a simple solution using traditional networking methods. But it looks like I'm going to have to do a lot of reading :).

Comment: If you're trying to access your containers from other containers, then linking is the correct answer. --link memcached1:mc would link your container named memcached1 to the hostname 'mc' inside the docker container you're starting.