# two docker app container on one nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, containers, hhvm

I try to serve 2 web applications that should be powered by hhvm. It is easy to build up one docker image that includes nginx and the default.conf. But now where I will get `n` apps as microservices I want to test them and share the nginx container as I proceed with others like DB e.g.

So when nginx is externally accessed with hhvm do I have to provide hhvm on this image too? Or can I refer it to the debian where hhvm is already provided? Then, I could store the `nginx.conf` with something like this:

```
upstream api.local.io {
   server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream booking.local.io {
   server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

How can I set up a proper nginx container for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828699/multiple-docker-containers-as-web-server-on-a-single-ip/27828950#27828950

Comment: It is no duplicate I want to know how to configure the nginx container not an Apache or just the ports

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can create another nginx container with an `nginx.conf` that is configured similarly to this:

```
upstream api {
   # Assuming this nginx container can access 127.0.0.1:5000
   server 127.0.0.1:3000;
   server server2.local.io:3000;
}

upstream booking {
   # Assuming this nginx container can access 127.0.0.1:5000
   server 127.0.0.1:5000;
   server server2.local.io:5000;
}

server {
    name api.local.io;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}

server {
    name booking.local.io;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://booking;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I have this in my hhvm container have this line in it:
`- ./hhvm/application:/usr/share/nginx/html` how can I tell the nginx container hey on port 80 for this site look at 127.0.0.1:9000 because I exposed the hhvm port 9000 for nginx

Comment: This help me so much. Thank you.